# Python Regex: Identify the first name

Tags: python, regex

I need to filter only the word which is "**shutdown**" alone. Its mentioned in seperate line. But also its available in between different line as well. i have used this filter "**^shutdown**" and "**^(shutdwon)**", its not helping me.

I am using python program to filter.

```
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/19
 switchport access vlan 102
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 100
 qos trust device cisco-phone
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/20
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/21
 description Test AP 335
 switchport access vlan 999
 switchport mode access
 shutdown
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/22
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/23
 switchport access vlan 102
 switchport shutdown mode access
 switchport voice vlan 100 shutdown
```

Comment: Can you post expected output please?

Comment: Output = shutdown. Which is below the line **interface GigabitEthernet5/21**. No other word contains on that line, only shutdown word will be there. some other lines are there which contains shutdown i dont want those lines. I need only the line which got the shutdown only. please let me know if i am not clear. Thanks !!!

Comment: `^shutdown` matches the string "shutdown" at the beginning of the line, but in your example input there are spaces between the beginning of the line and the word "shutdown".

Comment: Those are network switch interfaces. there is no spaces between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match only word `shutdown` in line, you can use this example (key is using flag `re.MULTILINE`, because we are using `^` and `$` in our regex):

```
data = """!
interface GigabitEthernet5/19
 switchport access vlan 102
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 100
 qos trust device cisco-phone
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/20
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/21
 description Test AP 335
 switchport access vlan 999
 switchport mode access
 shutdown
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/22
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/23
 switchport access vlan 102
 switchport shutdown mode access
 switchport voice vlan 100 shutdown"""

import re

print(re.findall(r'^\s*(shutdown)\s*$', data, flags=re.MULTILINE))
```

This will print:

```
['shutdown']
```

[Detailed explanation](https://regex101.com/r/cLvlAh/1) on Regex101 here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are treating whole string as a single variable. Here is a code

```
import re

fp = open('testfile_data', 'r')
text = fp.read()
fp.close()
value = re.findall(r'^ shutdown$', text, re.M)
print('Input')
print(text)
print('Output')
print(value)
```

Here testfile_data contains same data as you provided. Here is the output

```
Input
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/19
 switchport access vlan 102
 switchport mode access
 switchport voice vlan 100
 qos trust device cisco-phone
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/20
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/21
 description Test AP 335
 switchport access vlan 999
 switchport mode access
 shutdown
 spanning-tree portfast
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/22
!
interface GigabitEthernet5/23
 switchport access vlan 102
 switchport shutdown mode access
 switchport voice vlan 100 shutdown
Output
[' shutdown']
```